# Download file from Document Library using Lists.asmx

Tags: development

How can I download files from document library using Lists.asmx web service ? How do I instantiate an object of Lists web service in my code ? Does any one have complete code for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [How to download files from a SharePoint document library remotely
  via Lists.asmx webservice (SPS 2003/ MOSS 2007)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx)

And if you really want complete code here it is (copied, pasted, formatted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using SiteDataWebService;

namespace SiteDataWebService
{
    class Program
    {
         public static void DownLoadAttachment(string strURL,string strFileName)
         {
             HttpWebRequest request;
             HttpWebResponse response = null;

             try
             {
                 request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);
                 request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                 request.Timeout = 10000;
                 request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                 Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
                 //Write to disk
                 FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\\DownLoads\\" +strFileName, FileMode.Create);
                 byte[] read = new byte[256];
                 int count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                 while (count > 0)
                 {
                     fs.Write(read, 0, count);
                     count = s.Read(read, 0, read.Length);
                 }
                 //Close everything
                 fs.Close();
                 s.Close();
                 response.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);}
             }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument resdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        XmlNode resnode = null;
        string strURL = "";
        string strFileName = "";
        try
        {
            ListsService.Lists objLists = new SiteDataWebService.ListsService.Lists();
            objLists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            objLists.Url = "http://[SITENAME]:34028/sites/TestSite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx"; // change the URL to your sharepoint site
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields","");
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"QueryOptions", "");
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml ="<IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>";
            ndViewFields.InnerXml = "";
            ndQuery.InnerXml = "";
            try
            {
                XmlNode ndListItems = objLists.GetListItems("Shared Documents", null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null); // you can change the document library name to your custom document library name
                XmlNodeList oNodes = ndListItems.ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode node in oNodes)
                {
                    XmlNodeReader objReader = new XmlNodeReader(node);
                    while(objReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (objReader["ows_EncodedAbsUrl"] != null && objReader["ows_LinkFilename"]!=null)
                        {
                            strURL = objReader["ows_EncodedAbsUrl"].ToString();
                            strFileName = objReader["ows_LinkFilename"].ToString();
                            DownLoadAttachment(strURL,strFileName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message:\n" + ex.Message + "\nDetail:\n" + ex.Detail.InnerText + "\nStackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use this code snippet?
I paste the code in VS2005 C#, but I can't compile.
I obtain error concerning ListsService: impossible find the type or the name of the namespace 'ListsService'; probably is missing a directive using or a reference to an assemnbly"
I also tried to create a web reference to the _vti_bin/Lists.asmx of my WSS site and naming it "ListsService", as suggested in another forum; now I have only this two errors, instead of much more previously obtained

Comment: Franceso: You must create a .cs file with wsdl.exe tool and add it to your project. If you want to add a DLL then you need to use csc.exe to convert your .cs file into a DLL.
Both wsdl and csc tools are command-line tools.